# How to print rows of data where the difference in columns is >1

Tags: pandas, dataframe

the data table i'm using is:

```
enter code here
|State| Sno Center|     Mar-21| Apr-21|
|AP 1 | Guntur      |     121  | 121.1 |
|   2 | Nellore     |   118.8  | 118.3|
|   3 | Visakhapatnam|  131.6 | 131.5|
|ASM  | 4   Biswanath-| 123.7 | 124.5|
|   5 | Doom-Dooma   |   127.8 |128.2|
|   6 | Guwahati      | 125.9  |128.2|
|   7 | Labac-Silchar|  114.2 | 115.4|
|   8 | Numaligarh-  |  114.2  | 115.1|
|   9 | Sibsagar      | 117.7  | 117.3|
| 10|  Munger-Jamalpur|117.2  |  118.3|
```

I want to find the difference between the columns Mar-21 and Apr-21 and print those rows only where the difference is >1.
I tried the following

from numpy import median
import pandas as pd
from pandas.core.tools.numeric import to_numeric

```
df=pd.read_csv('CPIIW_421a.csv')

mydiff=(df['Apr-21']-df['Mar-21'])
print(mydiff)
df['diff']=(df['Apr-21']-df['Mar-21'])
print(df['diff'])
```

this code put displays only one column of difference as under, instead of details of rows.

```
0 |    0.1|
1 |   -0.5|
2 |   -0.1|
3 |    0.8|
4 |    0.4|
```

---

I need all rows display where difference is >1.
How I need to proceed further.
I also want to  copy the required data in a new csv file. please advise.
I am a beginner.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need this in your last print:

```
print(df.loc[df['diff'] > 1])
```

to save it to csv:

```
df.loc[df['diff'] > 1].to_csv('yourcsv.csv')
```

Comment: thanks. it is a solution I was looking for many days desperately before coming here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try as follows

```
df_new = df[(df["Apr-21"]-df["Mar-21"]) > 1].copy()
```

For example

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'State':[1,2,3,4,5,6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 
                         'Sno Center': ["Guntur", "Nellore", "Visakhapatnam", "Biswanath", "Doom-Dooma", "Guwahati", "Labac-Silchar", "Numaligarh", "Sibsagar", "Munger-Jamalpu"], 
                         'Mar-21': [121, 118.8, 131.6, 123.7, 127.8, 125.9, 114.2, 114.2, 117.7, 117.7],
                         'Apr-21': [121.1, 118.3, 131.5, 124.5, 128.2, 128.2, 115.4, 115.1, 117.3, 118.3]})
df
State   Sno Center  Mar-21  Apr-21
0   1   Guntur  121.0   121.1
1   2   Nellore     118.8   118.3
2   3   Visakhapatnam   131.6   131.5
3   4   Biswanath   123.7   124.5
4   5   Doom-Dooma  127.8   128.2
5   6   Guwahati    125.9   128.2
6   7   Labac-Silchar   114.2   115.4
7   8   Numaligarh  114.2   115.1
8   9   Sibsagar    117.7   117.3
9   10  Munger-Jamalpu  117.7   118.3

df_new = df[(df["Apr-21"]-df["Mar-21"]) > 1].copy()
```

The result

```
df_new
State   Sno Center  Mar-21  Apr-21
5   6   Guwahati    125.9   128.2
6   7   Labac-Silchar   114.2   115.4
```